# Помогите разобраться как получить доступ к структуре которая находиться в классе

Tags: c++, ооп

Я создал код с структурой в классе. Не могу понять как обратиться к елементам структуры вне класса.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<locale>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;
class Node {
 struct NONE {
     char name[80];
     char date[90];
     char m[90];
     char d[90];
     char num[90];
 };
 }obj1;
int main()
{

const int n = 2;
bool state;
char s[80];
Node* obj = new Node;
for (int i =0; i!=n; ++i)
{
    cout << ("Student name: ") << endl;
    cin >> obj[i].name;
    cout << obj[i].name << endl;
```

Comment: Самое забавное, что у вас все компилируется. https://ideone.com/YYMueA Проблема ваша главная в том, что вы выделили для `obj` память для одной `Node`, а используете как массив. `Node* obj = new Node[2];` хотя бы надо... Все остальное просто предупреждения — типа, что ваш **глобальный** `obj` в функции не виден, потому что там вы объявили новый, локальный `obj`.

Comment: А если к примеру я сделал структуру приватной, то как мне обратиться к её елементам

Comment: class Node {
  struct NONE {
   char name[80];
   char date[90];
   char m[90];
   char d[90];
   char num[90];
  };
}obj1;

Comment: Там же нельзя обратиться к её елементам напрямую. Вот это я пытаюсь понять, но что то не выходит

Comment: приводите реальный пример в вопросе, который не работает и вопрос что не получается.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include<locale>
 #include<Windows.h>

 using namespace std;
 class Node {
  struct NONE {
   char name[80];
   char date[90];
   char m[90];
   char d[90];
   char num[90];
  };
}obj1;
int main()
{

 const int n = 2;
 bool state;
 char s[80];
 Node* obj = new Node;
 for (int i =0; i!=n; ++i)
 {
  cout << ("Student name: ") << endl;
  cin >> obj[i].name;
  cout << obj[i].name << endl;}`

Comment: Вот сдесь я создал структуру приватную в классе, пытался обратиться к её елементам, но у меня не получаеться

Comment: под вопросом кнопочка **править**

Comment: у вас класс пустых объектов. так как объявление структуры создаёт тип, а не поле с данными. И у пустого объекта и взять нечего.

Answer (score 2):

Отвлекаясь — зачем вы все время тягаете за собой неиспользуемую глобальную переменную?...

В вашем коде

```
class Node
{
    struct NONE
    {
        char name[80];
        char date[90];
        char m[90];
        char d[90];
        char num[90];
    };
};
```

`NONE` — объявление типа, но не элементе. Вот если бы вы написали, например,

```
class Node
{
    struct
    {
        char name[80];
        char date[90];
        char m[90];
        char d[90];
        char num[90];
    } NONE;
};
```

то был бы у вас член `NONE` с типом безымянной структуры. И обращаться надо было бы так:

```
    cin >> obj[i].NONE.name;
    cout << obj[i].NONE.name << endl;
```

Но! У вас она, будучи объявлена в классе без модификаторов доступа, является `private`, а значит, за пределами класса недоступна — только членам класса и дружественным функциям.

Так что у вас при этом варианты — или объявлять член `NONE` как `public`, или работать с ним через открытые функции-члены класса.

Сама парадигма ООП предполагает, что работать с объектами следует только через их функции-члены; никто снаружи не должен знать, что там у него внутри, какие именно члены-данные и какого типа.